# Port remains occupied even if the application is shutdown

Tags: windows, sockets, service, tcp, network-programming

I am facing issue with c++ service which uses port 30015.It runs fine,but sometime it fails to start as the port 30015 is occupied and bind fails with error WSAEADDRINUSE.

I ran netstat command to know the port status

```
 netstat -aon | findstr 30015
```

Output:

TCP 0.0.0.0:30015 0.0.0.0 LISTENING 6740

I checked the PID 6740 in task manager,this PID is not be taken by an process.

After searching in the net, I used TCPVIEW to see the status of the port. TCPView is showing port in listening mode and process name is "non-existance".

Application basically compress,decompress the file using 7za. Application listen on 30015 port for request and than create a child process and pass the commandline to run 7za command to compress and decompress file.

Here child process doesn't uses socket. Server runs on the main thread and listen on port 30015. This problem comes after restart of the server.

Here child process does not use socket as such. Do I need to make bInheritHandle = FALSE ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure? This all sounds very confused. It's not possible for `netstat` to show a socket in the LISTEN state but for there to be no process -- especially if it shows the pid! You're confused because the process simply exited by the time you looked in Task Manager. All TCP connections in netstat are associated with a running process (except for unusual cases like TIME-WAIT sockets). So, find out which process has the socket open.

Secondly, I think you're trying to say that using `bInheritHandles=TRUE` as an argument to `CreateProcess` can lead to handle leaks. Only you have your code -- why not just look at the handles in your child and see if you do have a leak? It is only possible to use `bInheritHandles=TRUE` with great discipline, in the hands of novice programmers it will only lead to bugs. Create a named pipe with a suitable security descriptor, pass the name on the commandline to the child, and connect back, rather than using handle inheritance which is much too coarse-grained.

Finally, just to make sure, you do know to bind listening sockets with `SO_REUSEADDR` to prevent conflicting with active sockets using the same port? (`SO_REUSEADDR` still won't let two passive sockets be created on the same address/port combination, although it is a bit broken on Windows.)

Comment: Yes this true.I cross verified using TCPVIew utility.There it shows process name as non-existence and it occupied the port.I wanted to know what if I make bInheritHandles= FALSE.Will this restrict child process access to socket.

Comment: I am creating child process to execute 7za (compress/decompress) command.child process is not using socket or port.Even if child process not using socket/port as such,do bInheritHandles =TRUE makes child process to occupy socket/port

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can happen on Windows. If you've created a child process that inherits handles from the parent process then that includes TCP server sockets in the LISTEN state that will always be listed as owned by the parent PID even after that PID has died.

These sockets will disappear when all child processes that you spawned have exited, causing the reference count on their handles to reach zero.

From a security standpoint you should not use inter-process handle-inheritance, particularly when launching a 3rd part application, unless you have a good reason to need the feature.

Comment: You mean I need to pass bInheritHandles =FALSE to CreateProcess is it?

Comment: Right. There's no need for 7za to inherit any of your open handles if it's just receiving everything it needs on the command line e.g. input/output filenames and compression/decompression option flags.